# did Allah (swt) already knew Iblis wouldn't prostrate in front of Adam?

Tags: allah, shaitan, prophet-adam

as everything written already in the Preserved Tablet (al-Lawhu 'l-Mahfuz)

Comment: Allah (swt) is omniscient. Of course he would know why would he?